# Convert code from C++ to C: `a+b > b+a` where a and b are `string`

Tags: c++, c

Does anyone know how to convert this line from C++ to C programming language? 
i wrote this code in C++ and i want to convert it in C.

```
bool compare(string a, string b)
{
return a+b > b+a;
}
```

it's a compare function in qsort

i want to compare by "a+b > b+a" to solve that problem:Such as if there are 4 integers as 123, 124, 56, 90 then the following integers can be made "1231245690, 1241235690, 5612312490, 9012312456, 9056124123" etc. In fact 24 such integers can be made. But one thing is sure that 9056124123 is the largest possible integer which can be made.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yes i tried something like that return strcmp(strcat(*ib,*ia), strcat(*ia,*ib));

Comment: @PvzAKho, then you should add your attempt to the question body. Please do so

Comment: You can't `strcat` like that. You need to be sure that the destination buffer has enough space.

Comment: There is no `string` in C. How will you be passing the strings to this function in C?

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: Construct the strings for comparison locally.

Comment: the code is c++ @RustyX

Comment: To determine the desired result it is actually not necessary to concatenate the strings! The comparison can entirely be run based on substring comparison.

Comment: You can compare them manually char-by-char with a loop, that will be faster than constructing new strings. You just need to continue from `b` as soon as `a` hits `'\0'`. BTW such a compare formula (a+b <=> b+a) **makes no sense**.

Comment: i want to compare by "a+b > b+a" to solve that problem:Such as if there are 4 integers as 123, 124, 56, 90 then the following integers can be made "1231245690, 1241235690, 5612312490, 9012312456, 9056124123" etc. In fact 24 such integers can be made. But one thing is sure that 9056124123 is the largest possible integer which can be made.

Comment: Any particular reason? `std::sort` is still part of the standard library.

Comment: Yes,but how @molbdnilo

Comment: Do you even need to concatenate? If one string is less/same/greater than the other, so will their mutual concatenations be. Note that comparing strings is not the same as comparing numbers: `"124" > "1234"`. Perhaps you should convert them actually to numbers.

Comment: converting code from c++ to c == converting a Tesla to a model T Ford. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you expect without any concatenation:

```
int compare(char *a, char *b)
{
    char *p1, *p2;
    int i, len = strlen(a) + strlen(b);

    p1 = a;
    p2 = b;
    for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
        if (*p1 > *p2) {
            return 1;
        } else if (*p1 < *p2) {
            return -1;
        }
        p1++;
        p2++;
        if (!*p1) {
            p1 = b;
        }
        if (!*p2) {
            p2 = a;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The pointers `p1` and `p2` start at the beginning of `a` and `b` respectively and compare character by character for each one, then each pointer is incremented if there's no difference.  When either pointer encounters a null byte, it is reassigned to the start of the other variable to continue from there.

We start by getting the combined length of the two strings and run through the loop that many times.

Working on the decimal representation of the two numbers as strings is actually simpler than dealing with them as integers, as the latter would involve determining the number of decimal digits and multiplying accordingly.  This method also isn't constrained by the bounds of whatever integer type you may be using.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a code without any extra allocation, you can try :

```
#include <string.h>
int compare(const char* a, const char* b)
{
  int a_len = strlen(a), b_len = strlen(b);
  int min_len = (a_len < b_len) ? a_len : b_len;
  int result = strncmp(a, b, min_len);
  if (result != 0)
     return result;
  if (a_len == b_len)
    return 0;
  if (a_len < b_len)
    result = strncmp(b, b+a_len, b_len-a_len);
  else
    result = strncmp(a+b_len, a, a_len-b_len);
  if (result != 0)
     return result;
  if (a_len < b_len)
    result = strncmp(b+(b_len-a_len), a, a_len);
  else
    result = strncmp(b, a+(a_len-b_len), b_len);
  return result;
}
```

It does at most 3 string comparisons. The return value follows the definition of [strncmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp).